# svg to html to pdf conversion

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, graphael

I would like to use graphael to draw a simple chart on a webpage (that has other html). Is there a way to convert the chart to a .gif or .png image at the same time that it is drawn?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a few ways.  The commercial product Prince ( http://www.princexml.com ) does this, as does the open source Inkscape ( http://inkscape.org/ ). In fact, there are a fair number of HTML/SVG->PDF converters on the market.

The Kendo UI DataViz library (a competitor to graphael) has some sample code in .NET for doing this server side with Inkscape: http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/dataviz/chart/kendo-ui-chart-export.aspx